# Please explain What's wrong with this C code?

Tags: c, gcc

What I am trying is to get all the file present in a directory and then add a .enc extension to this file. Example- Let File.txt is present then I will perform some encryption related task and after that the new file name would be File.txt.enc

Here is my code:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    char *name;
    int val;
    d = opendir(".");
    if (d)
    {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
        {
            name=dir->d_name;
            printf("File Found:%s\n",name);
            strcat(name,".enc");
            val=rename(dir->d_name,name);
            if(val==0)
                    printf("Encrypted File:%s\n",name);
            else
                    perror("Error: ");
        }
        closedir(d);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

But I am getting a output like this......

```
File Found:write_pgm_img.c
Error: : No such file or directory
File Found:realloc.c
Error: : No such file or directory
File Found:getusage.txt
Error: : No such file or directory
File Found:directory.c
Error: : No such file or directory
```

As you can see "No such file or directory" error. But I can't understand why?? Please explain.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to print `dir->d_name` and `name` before rename

Comment: Does `write_pgm_img.c.enc` seem like a valid file name? Hello debugger, my old friend... I've come to talk with you again...

Comment: On what platform you are? `opendir()` is not a standard C function.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 I am using gcc compiler. And Opendir() is a standard function in GNU C Library....

Comment: @Rupam098 GCC can be used on windows that does not have the `opendir()` function and many embedded platforms that do not have the concepts of directories, not even files. If you use functions specific to POSIX, Linux or the GNU C Library, please add a tag or specify it in the question.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 After you said I cheack it carefully. And I found that dirent.h library is one of the default libraries like stdio.h in any C compiler.I successfully run the code in TURBO C under Windows.So I think there should not be any problem. Am I right??? If no then feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are messing up pointers and memory content:

```
            name=dir->d_name;
            printf("File Found:%s\n",name);
            strcat(name,".enc");
            val=rename(dir->d_name,name);
```

After the first line, `name` and `dir->d_name` point to the same memory address. This means you try to add a suffix to the memory where `dir->d_name` is located.
You cannot expect that memory to be large enough to hold your suffix. (But in this case this does not cause the problem as your file names seem to be short enough)

Also your update will affect both `name` and `dir->d_name` in the same way which makes renaming pointless because you try to rename `getusage.txt.enc` to `getusage.txt.enc`

A possible solution could be:

```
        char name[sizeof(dir->d_name)+4];
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
        {
            strcpy(name, dir->d_name);
            printf("File Found:%s\n",name);
            strcat(name,".enc");
            val=rename(dir->d_name,name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `name` & `dir->d_name` have the same address. Hence `strcat(name,".enc");` will update both `name` & `dir->d_nam`e and the source will have the prefix `'.enc'`

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps you're assuming that `name=dir->d_name` creates some new piece of data called `name`. It's an easy enough mistake to make, because in many programming languages that's exactly what would happen. In C though, you've just set a pointer called `name` to refer to the existing data called `d_name`.

If you want to append something to `d_name`, you probably need to copy it to a `char *` that references a piece of storage large enough to hold it, and the suffix, and the terminating null, and then copy the suffix onto the end of that new storage. Something like:

```
char *new_name = malloc (strlen (dir->d_name) + strlen (suffix) + 1);
strcpy (new_name, dir->d_name);
strcat (new_name, suffix);
...
free (new_name);
```

Probably there are many other ways to achieve the same thing. The fundamental point is that assigning pointer types in C does not allocate or duplicate storage.

Comment: Yes this was a mistake.I thought It like normal assignment and forgot that the pointer is pointing to a spacific memory address.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since `name` may not have a larger size, `strcat(name,".enc");` will may write past that size and causes UB. As others point out, this does not cause the ENOENT error you get (assuming you use linux).

To fix that you have to create a new, large enough buffer and copy the new name to it. This would also fix the error you get because this way you do not overwrite the old name.